# Define a function that returns the number of non-overlapping occurrences of a sub string in a string

Tags: python, string, count

Q> Suppose the count function for a string didn't exist. Define a function that returns the number of non-overlapping occurrences of a sub string in a string.

I think this problem means that if I type the string `"abcd"` then the result is 10?

I guess the substrings would be:

```
a
b
c
d
ab
bc
cd
abc
bcd
abcd
```

So the result is 10. Is it right?

Comment: Markdown formatting; removed double question marks

Answer (score 0):

Given the count function for a string counts the occurrences of a specific substring, it seems like the answer would attempt to mimic it rather than measure every possible substring. You can use the re module to accomplish a count of a substring. The findall function returns a list of matches, and the length can be used to find the count

```
import re
x ='thetheitem1thetheitem2'
len(re.findall(r'the',x))
```

4